# How to update a database user password in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am needing to update the password of one of the users in the database security folder in SQL Server 2012. Unfortunately, we do not have a DBA in-house and consequently needing some help. I've been told that I have sysadmin privileges on this SQL Server but I cannot find WHERE to update a user's password in the database.  When I googled this, msdn show me how to update a login in the SQL Server 2012 box but this user is NOT listed under the Security\Logins folder in this server but this user is only under the database\Security\Users folder.

I had tried the `ALTER LOGIN username WITH PASSWORD = 'password';` command but I only got this error:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Cannot alter the login 'ATM', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the difference between [logins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) and [users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) and how they relate to each other:

- Logins - Instance level principals that allow an entity to connect to the SQL Server instance.  They do not, by their nature, grant any access to databases on the instance.  The exception to this is a login with sysadmin rights can use a database because they are sysadmin, but because of sysadmin level permissions.
- Users - Database level principals that allow an entity to connect to a SQL Server database.  Users are associated with logins via SIDs, creating a relationship between the two and allowing a login to connect to the instance and then use the associated user to connect to the database.

What commonly happens with SQL authenticated logins and database users on a restore is that the SIDS will be out of sync or a login will not exist for a user in the database, thus breaking the relationship.  This relationship must be repaired before you can connect to the database using that login, because in the eyes of SQL Server those principals are no longer connected.  If the login doesn't exist, you will have to first [create it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) in order to associate it with the user:

```
--Windows login (Active Directory pass through)
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN\foo] FROM WINDOWS;

--SQL Authenticated 
CREATE LOGIN [foo] WITH PASSWORD='5+r0ngP@55w0rd';
```

Once the login exists, associate it with the user:

```
ALTER USER [foo] WITH LOGIN=[foo]
```

You can use the following query in the context of your database to check for orphans:

```
select
    dp.name [user_name]
    ,dp.type_desc [user_type]
    ,isnull(sp.name,'Orhphaned!') [login_name]
    ,sp.type_desc [login_type]
from   
    sys.database_principals dp
    left join sys.server_principals sp on (dp.sid = sp.sid)
where
    dp.type in ('S','U','G')
    and dp.principal_id >4
order by sp.name
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for taking the time to reply with a great explanation. Regards.